# Unable to deploy sandbox solution on SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, office365-apps

I have been trying to deploy a sandbox solution on SharePoint online but unable to deploy it. The technique I am following is to develop a sandbox solution on SharePoint 2013 on premises and extract .wsp file which I take to SharePoint online and upload this .wsp in **Site Settings** --> **Web Designer Galleries** --> **Solution**. But when I upload the solution it gives me the error below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGyCA.png)

After googling this issue I came across this article http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2016/08/sandbox-code-disabled-in-Office-365.html  which says that the activation of sandboxed solution is disabled last couple of weeks before. 
After more googling I found the solution of this issue from an article which asks me to set **Include Assembly in Package** property of my solution to **False**. This resolves the above activation of sandboxed solution issue but when I go to my page and try to add the web part it gives me this error “**$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;**”.

I tried a lot and invested my 2 days with no solution. Your support will be appreciated.
Thank You,

Comment: any one tagged has any solution ???

Comment: What does your Sandbox Solution accomplish?  If you are writing .Net code in your solution, it will no longer work in SharePoint Online since the code is in the .Net Assembly that you are excluding from your .wsp file.

Comment: I have also tried a webpart that contains  simple html tag <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1> with no dotnet code. Even I am not able to add this web part on my page.

Comment: WebParts rely on the coded parts of the infrastructure and won't work any more in o365.  If you want to continue down this path you are going to have to look into the SharePoint Add-in model or the new SharePoint Framework.  In particular you should look at the client side webpart model in the SP Framework since that should be easier and less time consuming that the infrastructure setup for the add-in model https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/05/04/sharepoint-developer-announcement-the-sharepoint-framework-an-open-and-connected-platform/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that the activation of sandbox solutions in O65 has been disabled. Microsoft has publicly announced the same with different articles.

- http://dev.office.com/blogs/removing-code-based-sandbox-solutions-in-sharepoint-online
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions/

Try the following and check if retracting and deploying the solution works for you.

> Open Visual Studio -> Build -> Select 'Retract'

Comment: It means I have to move my solution to client-side development. Thanks for your response.